# Random effect exactness in Bayesian vs Frequentist paradigms

Tags: regression, bayesian, mixed-model, inference, frequentist

In [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/606618/247274), Frank Harrell advocates for Bayesian methods when random effects are used. Now, he is a known Bayesian, so this is not surprising, but his expansion in the comments suggests a stronger advocacy for Bayesian modeling here than his usual.

> Everything in the frequentist domain is approximate when you have random effects whereas Bayes is exact. Bayes is also much easier to program for random effects, and to marginalize out the random effects for certain types of estimation. But even without random effects frequentist methods have problems being accurate enough. Take confidence intervals for logistic regression as an example, when the usual Wald method is used. With Bayes you get exact credible or HPD intervals because Bayes does not assume a quadratic log-likelihood like Wald tests do.

Could someone please explain in more detail what’s happening with Bayesian modeling of random effects vs doing so with frequentist modeling?

Comment: This is only a very indirect answer but to add random effects to any model using `Stan` takes about 2 additional lines of code.  To add random effects in a frequentist model procedure requires page after page of code.  For Bayes, posterior sampling is then done, and no quadrature and other approximations are needed as in frequentist.